# How can I use graphics method for AForge IntPoint truely?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I tried to write a code for detecting elips objects with Aforge blobcounter function but when I want to draw it with graphics I am getting an error.

The error is:

Argument 2:cannot covert from 'AForge.IntPoint' to 'System.Drawing.PointF'.What is the thing that I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
namespace blobdnm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog sfd = new OpenFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Image Files|*.bmp|All Files|*.*";
            sfd.InitialDirectory = ".";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = sfd.FileName;
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            BitmapData BmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            byte[] data = new byte[bmp.Width*bmp.Height*3];
            IntPtr ptr = BmpData.Scan0;
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, data.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width*bmp.Height*3; i=i+3)
            {
                double a = data[i] * 0.2125 + data[i + 1] * 0.7154 + data[i + 2] *0.0721;
                if(a>100)
                {
                    data[i] = 0;
                    data[i+1] = 0;
                    data[i+2] = 0;
                }
            }
            Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width,bmp.Height,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            BitmapData BmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0,BmpData2.Scan0, data.Length);
            bmp2.UnlockBits(BmpData2);
            ColorFiltering colorFilter = new ColorFiltering();
            BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
            blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;
            blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
            blobCounter.MaxWidth = 3000;
            blobCounter.MaxHeight = 3000;
            blobCounter.ProcessImage(BmpData2);
            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            List<IntPoint> edgePoints=null;
            for (int i = 0; i < blobs.Length; i++)
            {
                 edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);
                for (int k = 0; k < edgePoints.Count; k++)
                {
                    g.DrawPolygon(redPen, edgePoints[k]);  //This is the part that I am getting an error
                }
            }
            redPen.Dispose();
             g.Dispose();
             pictureBox1.Image = bmp2;
         }
         private System.Drawing.Point[] ToPointsArray(List<IntPoint> points)
         {
            System.Drawing.Point[] array = new System.Drawing.Point[points.Count];

             for (int i = 0, n = points.Count; i < n; i++)
             {
                 array[i] = new System.Drawing.Point(points[i].X, points[i].Y);
             }
             return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert [AForge.IntPoint](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/1903c369-158a-e135-7eb1-5115fd120be9.htm) into [System.Drawing.Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point) and then pass it to `Graphics.DrawPolygon()` method.
This will do the job:

```
public System.Drawing.Point ToPoint(IntPoint point)
{
    return new System.Drawing.Point(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

In fact you have method `ToPointsArray()` doing the same conversion but on the list of `IntPoint` in your code.